Matrix representation of elements in PSL(2,q) - SageMath
I just started using SageMath and am not sure how to represent the elements of PSL(2,q) as 2x2 matrices (instead of permutations).
For the case q = 7, I tried
MS = MatrixSpace(GF(7), 2)
gens = [MS([[2,0],[0,4]]),MS([[-1,1],[-1,0]])]
G = MatrixGroup(gens)
G.conjugacy_classes_representatives() # I want this to show representatives as 2x2 matrices

which generates SL(2,7) instead of PSL(2,7).
